# How do I tell dominate x or y direction the best way possible?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, unity-game-engine

Okay so I'm making a video game in Unity, and am currently working on the 2D four-way directional movement state machine. My Idle animation doesn't know what way to go. I've gone through this code x 100 and I'm almost positive there's a better way out there...

The X and Y are floating points so I need to compare them to Epsilon. I've done a switch statement and now this if statement. The ultimate end goal is a one calculation switch statement, because im basically doing 4 if statements here

```
private void SetCharacterDirection(float x, float y)
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(x) - Mathf.Abs(y) > Mathf.Epsilon)
    {
        _characterDirection = Mathf.Abs(x) > Mathf.Epsilon ? CharacterDirections.Right : CharacterDirections.Left;
    }
    else
    {
        _characterDirection = Mathf.Abs(y) > Mathf.Epsilon ? CharacterDirections.Up : CharacterDirections.Down;
    }
}
```

There is some kind of magic combination out there using absolutes, cosines, math.floor(), math.ceiling, or even a vector2; but I've been looking at this to long and can't see it. Please help.

Comment: You don't really need to use epsilon for greater-than / less-than comparisons - just for "equality," and C# is a lot more forgiving about float compares than C++.  Why are you comparing X and Y to each other? What do these represent?

Comment: They represent direction. I need the whole number closest to a whole value (1x, 1y, -1x, or -1y) if they are not both 0

Comment: For example: (0.4X, -0.5Y) == (0X, -1Y) also: (0.1X, -0.2Y) == (0X, -1Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want an up, down, left or right based on the input component with the largest magnitude.

Try this (I haven't compiled this)

```
private void SetCharacterDirection(float x, float y)
{
    var absX = Mathf.Abs(x);
    var absY = Mathf.Abs(y);

    if (absX > absY)
    {
      _characterDirection = Mathf.Sign(x) > 0 ? CharacterDirections.Right : CharacterDirections.Left;
    }
    else if (absX < absY)
    {
      _characterDirection = Mathf.Sign(y) > 0 ? CharacterDirections.Up : CharacterDirections.Down;
    }
    // implicitly ignore case where X == Y
}
```

Comment: you can't do (x == 0.0f && y == 0.0f) you need epsilon for that, documentation [here.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)
I've come across both of these solutions and may have been to tired to realize that there is no magic function to find it in one conditional because you are evaluating two different points. (hence two-dimensional). Although I must ask, why did you check for do nothing before anything else? fail fast?

Comment: The key calculation in the second method was incorrect, so I've removed it. Besides, it just obfuscates things and you'll get < epsilon perf. I removed the initial comparison and modified the `if` to silently ignore the condition where x ~= y.

Comment: I walked in circles a bit obsessing over this but your fresh eyes on it brought me back. Your latest revision is some clean code. Right on, and thank you much.